# Geting userId information in ExceptionFilterAttribute in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using asp.net web api project. I have added a `ExceptionFilterAttribute`.

```
public class ExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
               //How to get user id. 
        }
    }
```

In my project I have enabled anonymous authentication. I am trying to get userId using `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;` but the value is always a empty string. Do I need to include any nugget package to get the userId?

Sometimes, I may get request through a mobile client, in that case, how can I check for userId and how can I find if the request is made from mobile client?

Answer (score 0):

First, the correct syntax for getting userId is:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

More importantly, How can you get the userId for anonymous authentication? The user must be authenticated in order to get the userId. You must disable anonymous authentication, and enable Windows Authentication.

You can also go with Asp.Identity UseManager, and get the userId like:

```
RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId();
```